# Does laminate flooring go under a metal threshold like the original tile did?

Tags: flooring

I'm unsure if I need to cut and stop the laminate at the metal threshold or place it under it. The original tile that was removed went under the metal threshold so I would assume the laminate would also.....but am curious what the experts say.

There're three screws on the threshold to adjust the height - it's currently not fastened - just sitting on top in the picture. It can be level if it's screwed down and there were shims under it when the builder had tile under it also.

Here's a pic of the area in question and thanks! :

[image]